# iMacros with JS - Accessing csv file: How to change the value of n dynamically in {{!COLn}}

Tags: imacros

Am using iMacros with JS in Firefox.
To retrieve column data, I am using

```
SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}
```

How can I dynamically change the value 1 so that I shall retrieve data from other columns as well?

**Try1:**
I have set the value of n using:

```
iimSet("n",i);
```

and used like this:

```
SET !EXTRACT {{!COL{{n}}}}
```

This prints as `_undefined_`

**Try2**
I have set value like this:

```
iimSet("columnName","!COL"+i);
```

where i is iterated in for loop.
and used like this:

```
SET !EXTRACT {{columnName}}
```

This prints only the !COL1, !COL2, !COL3 as text.

PFB my complete code:

```
var PickPackFilePath = "D:\\";
var PickPackData = "PickPackData.csv";

var initCSV; 
initCSV =  "CODE:";
initCSV +=  "SET !DATASOURCE " + PickPackFilePath + PickPackData + "\n";
initCSV +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1" + "\n";
initCSV +=  "SET !EXTRACT {{!COL{{n}}}}" + "\n";

var i;
for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
{
    iimSet("n",i);
    iimPlay(initCSV);
    alert(iimGetLastExtract(1));
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close to the right solution. Here it is:

```
var PickPackFilePath = "D:\\";
var PickPackData = "PickPackData.csv";

var i;
for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
{
    var initCSV; 
    initCSV =  "CODE:";
    initCSV +=  "SET !DATASOURCE " + PickPackFilePath + PickPackData + "\n";
    initCSV +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1" + "\n";
    initCSV +=  "SET !EXTRACT {{!COL" + i + "}}" + "\n";

    iimPlay(initCSV);
    alert(iimGetLastExtract(1));
}
```